ESP32 SmartConfig with flutter application not provisioning
I am using ESP32s, and am trying to setup a smartconfig provisioning process using the esp_smartconfig flutter package
I had previously used ESPTOUCH_SMARTCONFIG package and had that working however have decided for a rewrite in this package.
When running esp_smartconfig_get_version() on the ESP32 I am getting
ESP SMARTCONFIG VERSION: V3.0.1
What am I doing wrong? I have a feeling its that i'm using the wrong version of smartconfig / esptouch on the esp side?
any help would be appreciated
In order to start the provisioning on the arduino I am doing
DEBUG_PRINT("Starting Smartconfig");

WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
WiFi.beginSmartConfig(SC_TYPE_ESPTOUCH_V2, "1234567890123456");
DEBUG_PRINT("ESP SMARTCONFIG VERSION: " + String());

  

//Wait for SmartConfig packet from mobile
DEBUG_PRINT("Waiting for SmartConfig.");
while (!WiFi.smartConfigDone()) {
delay(500);
Serial.print(".");
}

  

DEBUG_PRINT("");
DEBUG_PRINT("SmartConfig received.");

if (waitForWifi(50, "SmartConfig")) {
    writeToEEPROM();
    return true;
}

DEBUG_PRINT("");

On the Flutter Side I am running on a Stateful Loading Widget
@override  
void initState() {  
  super.initState();  
  provisioner.listen((response) {  
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(  
      "/configurenewdevice",  
      arguments: CurrentDevice(  
          (supabase.auth.currentUser != null  
              ? supabase.auth.currentUser!.id  
              : ""),  
          response.bssidText),  
    );  
  });  
  startProvisioning(widget.ssid, widget.password);  
}  
  
Future<void> startProvisioning(ssid, password) async {  
  print("Started Provisioning");  
  setState(() {  
    isSearching = true;  
  });  
  
  try {  
    await provisioner.start(ProvisioningRequest.fromStrings(  
      ssid: ssid,  
      password: password,  
    ));  
  } catch (e, s) {  
    print(e);  
    showUserError(context, e.toString());  
    setState(() {  
      isSearching = false;  
    });  
  }  
}

Console log wise I am receiving [14:50:09.312] [esp_smartconfig] [INFO] Provisioning started From the Flutter app.
and on the ESP I am getting
.........[  5201][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 29 - SC_SCAN_DONE
.......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................[200618][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 30 - SC_FOUND_CHANNEL
....[202752][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 31 - SC_GOT_SSID_PSWD
.....[205185][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 5 - STA_DISCONNECTED
[205185][W][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1057] _eventCallback(): Reason: 201 - NO_AP_FOUND
[205225][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1077] _eventCallback(): WiFi Reconnect Running
.....[207719][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 5 - STA_DISCONNECTED
[207720][W][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1057] _eventCallback(): Reason: 201 - NO_AP_FOUND

